# Integer give wrong division

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

i am coding this school assignement that says to convert a number into a text

Ex : 20 should be viewed in the programme like this ==> twenty

and i am having this problem

```
Dim num,y As Integer

 num = 26

 y = num / 10
```

the result of this is 2.6 but since its integer.

the result that should be stock in y

is " 2 " but instead it stocks "3"

i am didnt have any problems with C++

please can someone explain the problems plus the way of how to fix it
thank you in advance

Comment: Seems like VB.NET has a \ operator to do integer division and also rounds floating-point numbers when converting them to integers AFAICT. This was based on a few seconds of research, so forgive me if either of those is off.

Comment: When tagging, only include the tags which are relevant to your question.  c++ here has nothing to do with the problem or solution.

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN [VB.Net Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ex274z.aspx)

> Integer division is carried out using the \ Operator (Visual Basic).
>   Integer division returns the quotient, that is, the integer that
>   represents the number of times the divisor can divide into the
>   dividend without consideration of any remainder. Both the divisor and
>   the dividend must be integral types (SByte, Byte, Short, UShort,
>   Integer, UInteger, Long, and ULong) for this operator. All other types
>   must be converted to an integral type first.

While [/ Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25bswc76.aspx)

> Divides two numbers and returns a floating-point result.
>   Before division is performed, any integral numeric expressions are
>   widened to Double. If you assign the result to an integral data type,
>   Visual Basic attempts to convert the result from Double to that type.

So

```
y = num / 10  = 3 
y = num \ 10  = 2
```

Looking at the IL assembly of

```
Sub Main
    Dim num as Integer = 26
    Dim result as integer  = num / 10
    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub

IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s    1A 
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // num
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // num
IL_0004:  conv.r8     
IL_0005:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 00 24 40 
IL_000E:  div         
IL_000F:  call        System.Math.Round
IL_0014:  conv.ovf.i4 
IL_0015:  stloc.1     // result
IL_0016:  ldloc.1     // result
IL_0017:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

You could easily spot the call to System.Math.Round and the conversion of the returning value of the floating point division to an integer